# Checking elements in rows and cols of 2D array in Java of arbitrary size

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to check the rows and the columns of 2D array of arbitrary size. For example, user wants to print NxN size board. In this case, we can't just check for the positions(rows and cols) as we do in fixed length of 2D array. My first idea was to check each if array[i][j]==array[i][j+1], but this obviously won't work and will crash due to the `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception, as well as wont check the whole length of rows/cols.

Any ideas/suggestions?

My current flawed idea:

```
for (int i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j<arr[i].length-1; j++){
               if (arr[i][j]!=arr[i][j+1]){
                   //do something..
           }
       }
```

Comment: I think you need to post some code to show us what you have so far

Comment: arr[i][j]!=arr[i][j+1] <-- you need a length check before the 'j+1'

Comment: Do you mean that i need to write a conditional for length check or one of the indexes need an additional length property (if i can say in this way)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `Array.length` property (it's a property, not a method, note!), to determine how wide your array is. More examples etc. [here](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Java-array-size-explained-by-example)

Comment: At the moment i have two for loops that iterates through the board.length and i have the condition that i mentioned earlier. Or you had something different in your comment?